# Hot deploy project with a lot of static content in Weblogic

Tags: ant, weblogic, static-content

I have a Java EE application with a lot of static content: Javascript, images, css and such. Right now we are using weblogic plugin for eclipse to deploy our applications for testing purposes, but it's getting pretty slow and it's only going to get slower. Since we have a lot of javascript, it's often that we have to make small changes and test them in quick succession which is becoming a big headache.

We also want to move away from using weblogic plugin on Eclipse. We want to find a solution to deploying in a test environment in a way that it only copies content that was changed since the last deploy. We thought about using an Ant script, but all solutions I found on the internet involves making an .EAR  and copying it to the autodeploy folder in the test domain on the server. Which would not solve the problem since generating the ear would cause even further overhead.

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: can u store all your web content in a configured `virtual directory` outside of the weblogic folders? it can be anywhere on the server

Answer (score 1):

If you deploy to a local weblogic environment on the development machine you can use an exploded deployment (i.e. an unzipped war or ear).  All changes to static content and jsps will be available immediately for testing.

Comment: Can use [JDeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/overview/index.html) which comes with Integrated WebLogicServer.